# ECMAScript generators in Intel XDK Simulator

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

I am trying to use a generator declared with `function*` in Intel XDK. The simulate function in XDK is supposedly built on Chromium, though I am unable to tell which version ('about' box etc give no hint).

[This thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/560783) hints that such a thing should be possible yet when running the app in XDK Simulator I get `Syntax error: unexpected token *` on the line where `function*` appears.

How can I enable the necessary functionality in the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Simulate tab, start the simulator and open the debug console (using the "bug" icon on the Simulate tab toolbar). Type `top.process.versions` and you'll get an object containing the versions of the significant subsystems in the XDK. The XDK is built on top of node-webkit.

For example, in the 3759 release of the XDK, you'll see an object that looks like this:
`JavaScript
top.process.versions
Object {http_parser: "2.3", node: "0.12.7", v8: "3.28.71.19", uv: "1.6.1", zlib: "1.2.5"…}
chromium: "38.0.2125.122"
http_parser: "2.3"
modules: "14"
node: "0.12.7"
node-webkit: "0.11.7-rc10-dev"
nw-commit-id: "035e7e1-0108df2-b51d814-e04a66a-984caaa-cdd879e"
openssl: "1.0.1p"
uv: "1.6.1"
v8: "3.28.71.19"
zlib: "1.2.5"`

Comment: chromium: "38.0.2125.122". Generators not supported until chromium 39. That would explain it. Is there a way I can upgrade chromium within XDK, and if I do, will Intel Crosswalk webview support it as well?

Comment: Nope, you cannot update the Chromium that is in the XDK. However, next release (coming out shortly) will include an updated version of Chromium. I just checked a release candidate and it reports `chromium:"54.0.2840.99"` as the new version.

Comment: BTW -- what you see in the Simulator is *not* what you will see in a real-device > https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/intel-xdk-simulator-limitations <

Comment: Yes, though I read an FAQ for Crosswalk that says it tracks updates to Chromium about 2 weeks behind - which suggests it must be considerably more up to date than the simulator... can only try and see...

Comment: Yes, although you're limited to Crosswalk 19 with the XDK builders (see https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Release-dates for specific versions of Chromium used in Crosswalk). If you limit yourself to Android 5.0 and later devices your Chromium will be even later, since the WebView in Android 5+ is updated periodically by Google.